# Add Banner to tell App is Running in Background - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

How do I add the banner like in Google Maps, when it gets minimized, to tell iOS that the app is running in the background?

Comment: It's Background Modes.This is [a guide of it](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios).

Answer (score 1):

That is banner showed from **os** level. So We can't add external(custom) banner.

If you want to show os level banner, then you have to use background modes for location and others based on your project requirement.